# Java exceptions derivation

Tags: java, exception

I'm making my foo method throw an exception A as in

```
void foo() throws A {
    ....
    throw new A();
}
```

there is a pre-existing function bar() which calls foo, bar originally throws an exception B which is the superclass of A as in

```
void bar() throws B {
    foo();
    throw new B();
}
```

The problem is after adding throw new A in foo() the compiler is cribbing that i declare
that bar() also throws A. Isn't that implicit from the fact that A extends B? What is the workaround other than adding A in throws clause of bar()?

EDIT:

A is

```
public class A  extends B {
    private complex-type type;
    public A(String message);
    public A(complex-type type);
}
```

B is

```
public class B extends C {
    public B(String message);
}
```

Im thinking A's constructors do not have super calls. Could it be the reason?

Comment: You're right, this should work. That must mean that your code is not like this. Can you post a (trimmed-down) version of your actual code? With the actual declarations of the exceptions and the methods?

Comment: Could you please show your exception declarations for both `A` and `B`?

Comment: This is because `B` is *not* a superclass of `A` in your *actual* code. Your look-alike code compiles without an error ([link](http://ideone.com/huPPqG)).

Comment: made a lame mistake. Posted it as the answer :(

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the throws B from the function bar. The default action will be a rethrow of the exeption generated in foo().

You can catch this exception in the caller of foo(). Foo itself can ofcourse also throw an exception like in your case. In that case you do have to add the A in the throw clause

Thus.

```
void bar() throws A, B {
    foo();
    throw new B();
}
```

You can also simply throw Exception if both A and B extend the Throwable class or implement the Exception interface

Answer (score 0):

I think you swapped your A and B when you said A extends B.  Your example compiles fine:

```
public class Tmp { 

static class B extends Exception {
}

static class A extends B {
}

void foo() throws A {
    throw new A();
}

void bar() throws B {
    foo();
    throw new B();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys made a very very lame mistake. There were 2 occurences of the foo() call in that package i was looking at the wrong occurence. Thanks a ton and Sorry!!!